# Azure DevOps YAML Pipeline Approval using Multi-Stage

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I've recently tried converting our UI or Classic based Release pipeline over to a YAML based release pipeline.

We have three environments, initially a CD build will happily deploy to our Development environment.

From there we manually trigger a release (re: promotion) to Test, and then at some point, if we're all happy, manually promote to Production.

We know we can't mimic the manual promotion between releases stages as it's not currently supported, but from what I've read, we should be able to do the same thing by defining a security check for each environment where the manual promotion was requested.

The details for defining security checks are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass

I've since added that same security check to both Test and Production, but the releases still happen automatically.

Is there a sample of where this kind of approval process is mapped into the new YAML multi-stage releases?

So far I've added a security group to the Test and Production environment, via the `Approval and checks` feature on the Environments tab.

[image: Approvals and checks]

Comment: Can you share your YAML and your checks?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk It's done via the 'Approvals and Checks' function of the Environment, so it's not in the YAML itself... which is, as far as I can tell, what the link above is showing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check below YAML sample:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:

  - stage: build   
    jobs:
      - job: buildjob        
        steps:
          - checkout: none
      - deployment: DeployWeb
        pool:
          vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
        environment: 'Verify'

  - stage: deploy
    jobs:
      - deployment: DeployWeb
        displayName: deploy Web App
        pool:
          vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
        environment: 'Verify'
        strategy:
          # default deployment strategy, more coming...
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
              - script: echo my first deployment
```

---

In my scenario, I have one environment names `Verify`, and I added the `Approvals and Checks` for it.

To apply this `Approvals and Checks` into your multi-stage pipeline, you need make sure the corresponding environment has been targeted in YAML.

Another thing you need pay attention, is that until now, `Environment` can only be target in `deployment job` of YAML.

In another word, only the stage that configure the - `deployment: job` in it, can work with `Environment`. Also, will work with the `environment` that added the `Approvals and Checks`.

Comment: @merlin-liang-msft I've a stage for each deployment, where the environment is tagged via a variable - the aim is to reuse parts via a template. Could that be affecting it?

Comment: @Kieron. Do you mean you put the environment in the template, and re-use this template in YAML pipeline? If this, no, it won't. What I am using in my actual work is this way. Or you could share your pipeline script? Maybe I could find cause on why it does not be applied.

Comment: @merlin-liang-msft Sure...what's the best way to get it to you?

Comment: @Kieron, What about github?

Comment: @merlin-liang-msft Good shout! Here it is (note that the environments are controlled via variables, and the first and second deployment stage would become templates once it's working: https://gist.github.com/kieronlanning/804ebadd4175c19836bc05a058c03d21

Comment: @merlin-liang-msft By explicitly entering the environment as `'Test'` rather than `$(environment)` for example it seems to have worked!

However, it does mean we wouldn't be able to template those release seconds, right? - `Development`, `Test` and `Production` would have to be hard-coded.

Comment: @Kieron. May I know what is your environment name?I saw you are targeting 2 environments here in your YAML: `Deployment` and `Test`. There's no error on your YAML. It work fine on my side. Please make sure the `Deployment` and `Test` environments has created and configured the check before you run that pipeline.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210146/discussion-between-kieron-and-merlin-liang-msft).